# Smoothing irregular frequency data in R

Tags: r, smoothing

I have irregularly sampled heart rate data for 189 days. I need to somehow group my data set by the number of measurements in a day and then smooth the groups separately (maybe using fdata?).

Has anyone encountered this problem before and could help out with the code? Thanks in advance!

I've tried grouping the data with sqldf like this:

```
sql_iv <- "select year, month, day, 
rowSums(!is.na(y_t[-1][-2][-3]))
from y_t
group by year, month, day
order by year, month, day"

y1=sqldf(sql_iv)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : unrecognized token: "!"

Data structure for the first five days looks like this (columns go up to 406 because that's the highest amount of measurements in one day in my sample):

```
structure(list(year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), month = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 4), day = c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11), `1` = c(97, 63, 65, 54, 
59), `2` = c(98, 59, 55, 55, 59), `3` = c(95, 60, 58, 57, 56), 
    `4` = c(93, 59, 59, 61, 59), `5` = c(94, 59, 59, 61, 58), 
    `6` = c(94, 62, 56, 60, 54), `7` = c(92, 61, 58, 56, 55), 
    `8` = c(96, 60, 58, 57, 56), `9` = c(89, 62, 56, 56, 56), 
    `10` = c(90, 66, 53, 59, 56), `11` = c(93, 68, 54, 59, 51
    ), `12` = c(90, 65, 55, 58, 58), `13` = c(99, 65, 56, 57, 
    56), `14` = c(87, 62, 56, 57, 57), `15` = c(91, 59, 56, 56, 
    54), `16` = c(92, 57, 57, 55, 54), `17` = c(93, 57, 57, 55, 
    57), `18` = c(94, 57, 57, 55, 56), `19` = c(94, 58, 57, 54, 
    57), `20` = c(104, 58, 58, 55, 53), `21` = c(90, 58, 56, 
    53, 57), `22` = c(94, 52, 56, 49, 59), `23` = c(97, 51, 48, 
    52, 58), `24` = c(97, 53, 49, 55, 56), `25` = c(90, 53, 59, 
    54, 57), `26` = c(90.2960891723633, 54, 61, 54, 57), `27` = c(93, 
    54, 62, 54, 55), `28` = c(90, 54, 64, 64, 56), `29` = c(87, 
    54, 54, 53, 57), `30` = c(89, 55, 57, 54, 57), `31` = c(85, 
    56, 58, 55, 59), `32` = c(93, 60, 58, 53, 58), `33` = c(87, 
    61, 55, 54, 59), `34` = c(65, 68, 56, 55, 56), `35` = c(113, 
    60, 56, 56, 54), `36` = c(148, 60, 53, 56, 56), `37` = c(135, 
    59, 53, 57, 56), `38` = c(151, 58, 52, 57, 52), `39` = c(74, 
59, 52, 57, 54), `40` = c(138, 61, 52, 57, 54), `41` = c(113, 
58, 46, 58, 55), `42` = c(108, 57, 45, 58, 53), `43` = c(103, 
58, 47, 56, 53), `44` = c(98, 58, 51, 57, 60), `45` = c(90, 
58, 53, 58, 60), `46` = c(89, 58, 50, 57, 58), `47` = c(89, 
52, 50, 50, 59), `48` = c(88, 51, 48, 55, 59), `49` = c(89, 
52, 46, 55, 59), `50` = c(91, 53, 47, 53, 58), `51` = c(93, 
53, 48, 52, 59), `52` = c(93, 54, 49, 55, 61), `53` = c(94, 
56, 50, 55, 60), `54` = c(91, 54, 49, 59, 58), `55` = c(91, 
53, 50, 61, 59), `56` = c(85, 52, 51, 61, 60), `57` = c(84, 
55, 51, 61, 62), `58` = c(90, 61, 51, 60, 52), `59` = c(89, 
63, 45, 61, 52), `60` = c(90, 56, 47, 61, 57), `61` = c(90, 
56, 48, 61, 51), `62` = c(88, 55, 48, 53, 54), `63` = c(91, 
55, 49, 55, 55), `64` = c(85, 58, 53, 54, 54), `65` = c(82, 
57, 56, 50, 55), `66` = c(87, 60, 53, 52, 54), `67` = c(80, 
59, 52, 56, 52), `68` = c(75, 58, 51, 54, 52), `69` = c(75, 
57, 50, 56, 53), `70` = c(70, 59, 47, 60, 51), `71` = c(70, 
59, 47, 55, 54), `72` = c(70, 61, 49, 55, 57), `73` = c(69, 
61, 48, 53, 57), `74` = c(69, 61, 49, 52, 55), `75` = c(68, 
61, 47, 55, 66), `76` = c(64, 61, 50, 66, 62), `77` = c(67, 
57, 59, 85, 61), `78` = c(67, 60, 72, 65, 59), `79` = c(67, 
54, 59, 72, 80), `80` = c(67, 51, 78, 71, 68), `81` = c(66, 
54, 58, 69, 74), `82` = c(66, 58, 96, 70, 149), `83` = c(60, 
58, 62, 82, 54), `84` = c(63, 58, 58, 78, 93), `85` = c(63, 
65, 61, 86, 90), `86` = c(61, 67, 61, 72, 86), `87` = c(63, 
64, 65, 87, 88), `88` = c(64, 62, 68, 75, 84), `89` = c(NA, 
83, 70, 78, 81), `90` = c(NA, 79, 75, 79, 106), `91` = c(NA, 
64, 67, 73, 95), `92` = c(NA, 68, 72, 77, 94), `93` = c(NA, 
79, 66, 71, 87), `94` = c(NA, 68, 75, 71, 89), `95` = c(NA, 
96, 68, 66, 95), `96` = c(NA, 95, 62, 70, 94), `97` = c(NA, 
95, 60, 75, 93), `98` = c(NA, 94, 61, 89, 92), `99` = c(NA, 
98, 61, 84, 98), `100` = c(NA, 96, 61, 72, 98), `101` = c(NA, 
105, 63, 68, 93), `102` = c(NA, 112, 62, 58, 94), `103` = c(NA, 
113, 60, 66, 89), `104` = c(NA, 91, 60, 60, 84), `105` = c(NA, 
89, 64, 65.1769714355469, 93), `106` = c(NA, 90, 70, 79, 
87), `107` = c(NA, 127, 62, 64, 78), `108` = c(NA, 127, 66, 
71, 83), `109` = c(NA, 144, 70, 60, 81), `110` = c(NA, 141, 
63, 58, 86), `111` = c(NA, 129, 91, 62, 77), `112` = c(NA, 
126, 59, 64, 94), `113` = c(NA, 125, 59, 63, 97), `114` = c(NA, 
128, 59, 61, 85), `115` = c(NA, 128, 58, 59, 80), `116` = c(NA, 
130, 59, 61, 87), `117` = c(NA, 123, 68, 61, 86), `118` = c(NA, 
125, 63, 64, 89), `119` = c(NA, 126, 59, 54, 87), `120` = c(NA, 
128, 56, 59, 85), `121` = c(NA, 122, 58, 57.6097602844238, 
79), `122` = c(NA, 122, 60, 55, 79), `123` = c(NA, 123, 67, 
56, 71), `124` = c(NA, 127, 60, 56, 75), `125` = c(NA, 107, 
64, 57, 71), `126` = c(NA, 127, 63, 56, 77), `127` = c(NA, 
119, 62, 55, 77), `128` = c(NA, 126, 63, 55, 72), `129` = c(NA, 
122, 63, 60, 85), `130` = c(NA, 125, 64, 58, 72), `131` = c(NA, 
124, 60, 75, 68), `132` = c(NA, 130, 65, 71, 69), `133` = c(NA, 
123, 74, 77, 70), `134` = c(NA, 107, 79, 63, 75), `135` = c(NA, 
122, 77, 86, 65), `136` = c(NA, 128, 79, 77, 69), `137` = c(NA, 
112, 65, 89, 77), `138` = c(NA, 122, 97, 64, 77), `139` = c(NA, 
119, 65, 57, 83), `140` = c(NA, 120, 92, 57, 89), `141` = c(NA, 
119, 74, 59, 78), `142` = c(NA, 116, 69, 60, 76), `143` = c(NA, 
122, 58, 58, 78), `144` = c(NA, 105, 65, 59, 72), `145` = c(NA, 
106, 62, 66, 78), `146` = c(NA, 118, 63, 65, 75), `147` = c(NA, 
107, 64, 63, 72), `148` = c(NA, 102, 58, 62, 70), `149` = c(NA, 
101, 60, 63, 78), `150` = c(NA, 139, 65, 63, 85), `151` = c(NA, 
140, 62, 72, 78), `152` = c(NA, 138, 58, 68, 81), `153` = c(NA, 
138, 59, 60, 77), `154` = c(NA, 137, 63, 60, 73), `155` = c(NA, 
130, 59, 69, 77), `156` = c(NA, 124, 55, 68, 82), `157` = c(NA, 
120, 61, 69, 74), `158` = c(NA, 119, 57, 61, 79), `159` = c(NA, 
110, 56, 62, 80), `160` = c(NA, 69, 57, 61, 79), `161` = c(NA, 
81, 62, 69, 80), `162` = c(NA, 87, 65, 74, 79), `163` = c(NA, 
101, 56, 58, 82), `164` = c(NA, 87, 56, 58, 67), `165` = c(NA, 
96, 61, 60, 79), `166` = c(NA, 79, 68, 60, 73), `167` = c(NA, 
79, 57, 59, 77), `168` = c(NA, 69.1876068115234, 57, 57, 
82), `169` = c(NA, 77, 55, 55, 73), `170` = c(NA, 75, 75, 
57, 69), `171` = c(NA, 73, 75, 55, 73), `172` = c(NA, 76, 
63, 57, 67), `173` = c(NA, 72, 55, 58, 82), `174` = c(NA, 
90, 56, 65, 72), `175` = c(NA, 81, 54, 60, 70), `176` = c(NA, 
83, 58, 65, 72), `177` = c(NA, 81, 63, 63, 84), `178` = c(NA, 
79, 59, 61, 74), `179` = c(NA, 163, 58, 86, 83), `180` = c(NA, 
96, 63, 70, 86), `181` = c(NA, 131, 66, 61, 81), `182` = c(NA, 
151, 68, 64, 71), `183` = c(NA, 151, 55, 68, 78), `184` = c(NA, 
167, 55, 74, 68), `185` = c(NA, 162, 54, 70, 68), `186` = c(NA, 
154, 52, 73, 72), `187` = c(NA, 153, 63, 67, 67), `188` = c(NA, 
157, 59, 64, 82), `189` = c(NA, 105, 64, 67, 70), `190` = c(NA, 
111, 83, 67, 68), `191` = c(NA, 102, 62, 66, 72), `192` = c(NA, 
97, 77, 64, 68), `193` = c(NA, 96, 86, 66, 68), `194` = c(NA, 
96.4385528564453, 75, 71, 70), `195` = c(NA, 94, 68, 78, 
72), `196` = c(NA, 96, 68, 92, 69), `197` = c(NA, 91, 68, 
105, 67), `198` = c(NA, 92, 70, 96, 63), `199` = c(NA, 91, 
70, 67, 60), `200` = c(NA, 90, 66, 64, 69), `201` = c(NA, 
85, 68, 60, 69), `202` = c(NA, 88, 62, 67, 61), `203` = c(NA, 
86, 116, 65, 66), `204` = c(NA, 85, 61, 66, 64), `205` = c(NA, 
88, 60, 67, 67), `206` = c(NA, 87, 63, 60, 69), `207` = c(NA, 
84, 64, 61, 66), `208` = c(NA, 70, 66, 64, 61), `209` = c(NA, 
77, 69, 55, 101), `210` = c(NA, 80, 74, 57, 58), `211` = c(NA, 
84, 71, 61, 69), `212` = c(NA, 71, 89, 55, 71), `213` = c(NA, 
70, 71, 75, 77), `214` = c(NA, 69, 76, 63, 76), `215` = c(NA, 
69, 78, 60, 74), `216` = c(NA, 68, 77, 58, 79), `217` = c(NA, 
70, 64, 64, 69), `218` = c(NA, 70, 89, 57, 68), `219` = c(NA, 
80, 121, 60, 96), `220` = c(NA, 73, 121, 60, 94), `221` = c(NA, 
69, 107, 95, 100), `222` = c(NA, 74, 93, 72, 87), `223` = c(NA, 
74, 125, 69, 103), `224` = c(NA, 68, 118, 67, 99), `225` = c(NA, 
78, 116, 71, 101), `226` = c(NA, 65, 116, 65, 99), `227` = c(NA, 
73, 118, 68, 100), `228` = c(NA, 68, 113, 62, 94), `229` = c(NA, 
72, 113, 67, 94), `230` = c(NA, 76, 114, 65, 100), `231` = c(NA, 
73, 119, 63, 101), `232` = c(NA, 69, 93, 64, 100), `233` = c(NA, 
72, 107, 66, 104), `234` = c(NA, 63, 108, 68, 85), `235` = c(NA, 
64, 78, 60, 105), `236` = c(NA, 67, 68, 56, 126), `237` = c(NA, 
73, 93, 60, 101), `238` = c(NA, 60, 95, 59, 112), `239` = c(NA, 
64, 104, 67, 122), `240` = c(NA, 68, 103, 74, 124), `241` = c(NA, 
62, 100, 74, 108), `242` = c(NA, 62, 102, 83, 120), `243` = c(NA, 
62, 106, 72, 122), `244` = c(NA, 67, 96, 70, 118), `245` = c(NA, 
61, 108, 68, 99), `246` = c(NA, 59, 107, 78, 113), `247` = c(NA, 
64, 108, 80, 114), `248` = c(NA, 62, 96, 76, 114), `249` = c(NA, 
62, 103, 79, 107), `250` = c(NA, 61, 113, 72, 96), `251` = c(NA, 
68, 108, 65, 82), `252` = c(NA, 63, 114, 66, 86), `253` = c(NA, 
64, 91, 64, 85), `254` = c(NA, 68, 91, 62, 113), `255` = c(NA, 
66, 89, 60, 114), `256` = c(NA, 63, 94, 56, 114), `257` = c(NA, 
57, 91, 56, 116), `258` = c(NA, 59, 104, 58, 113), `259` = c(NA, 
58, 101, 58, 119), `260` = c(NA, 61, 95, 59, 126), `261` = c(NA, 
61, 109, 59, 112), `262` = c(NA, 59, 109, 58, 104), `263` = c(NA, 
59, 105, 59, 96), `264` = c(NA, 58, 100, 63, 98), `265` = c(NA, 
62, 102, 60, 115), `266` = c(NA, 56, 113, 60, 101), `267` = c(NA, 
61, 105, 62, 94), `268` = c(NA, 58, 87, 63, 98), `269` = c(NA, 
61, 100, 59, 128), `270` = c(NA, 59, 93, 61, 127), `271` = c(NA, 
60, 93, 61, 121), `272` = c(NA, 60, 94, 61, 113), `273` = c(NA, 
58, 95, 60, 107), `274` = c(NA, 59, 99, 60, 92), `275` = c(NA, 
58, 99, NA, 104), `276` = c(NA, 56, 102, NA, 86), `277` = c(NA, 
55, 95, NA, 113), `278` = c(NA, 55, 95, NA, 131), `279` = c(NA, 
58, 94, NA, 107), `280` = c(NA, 57, 93, NA, 104), `281` = c(NA, 
62, 100, NA, 109), `282` = c(NA, 70, 131, NA, 124), `283` = c(NA, 
62, 126, NA, 119), `284` = c(NA, 56, 86, NA, 122), `285` = c(NA, 
59, 85, NA, 122), `286` = c(NA, 54, 115, NA, 104), `287` = c(NA, 
57, 101, NA, 91), `288` = c(NA, 87, 77, NA, 95), `289` = c(NA, 
90, 84, NA, 84), `290` = c(NA, 100, 77, NA, 102), `291` = c(NA, 
81, 104, NA, 102), `292` = c(NA, 61, 65, NA, 101), `293` = c(NA, 
95, 71, NA, 101), `294` = c(NA, 82, 78, NA, 107), `295` = c(NA, 
62, 59, NA, 106), `296` = c(NA, 72, 69, NA, 106), `297` = c(NA, 
69, 59, NA, 99), `298` = c(NA, 65, 61, NA, 148), `299` = c(NA, 
67, 60, NA, 118), `300` = c(NA, 59, 60, NA, 107), `301` = c(NA, 
83, 58, NA, 122), `302` = c(NA, 75, 60, NA, 126), `303` = c(NA, 
84, 59, NA, 121), `304` = c(NA, 55, 60, NA, 110), `305` = c(NA, 
73, 57, NA, 105), `306` = c(NA, 74, 57, NA, 79), `307` = c(NA, 
78, 64, NA, 71), `308` = c(NA, 68, 61, NA, 80), `309` = c(NA, 
69, 61, NA, 72), `310` = c(NA, 69, 59, NA, 72), `311` = c(NA, 
61, 58, NA, 83), `312` = c(NA, 60, 54, NA, 85), `313` = c(NA, 
58, 58, NA, 82), `314` = c(NA, 55, 58, NA, 86), `315` = c(NA, 
55, 56, NA, 82), `316` = c(NA, 56, 55, NA, 63), `317` = c(NA, 
56, 55, NA, 80), `318` = c(NA, 54, 55, NA, 57), `319` = c(NA, 
54, NA, NA, 98), `320` = c(NA, 54, NA, NA, 62), `321` = c(NA, 
52, NA, NA, 53), `322` = c(NA, 54, NA, NA, 52), `323` = c(NA, 
58, NA, NA, 52), `324` = c(NA, 62, NA, NA, 51), `325` = c(NA, 
60, NA, NA, 52), `326` = c(NA, 60, NA, NA, 54), `327` = c(NA, 
57, NA, NA, 51), `328` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 57), `329` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 57), `330` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 61), `331` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 62), `332` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 64), `333` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 64), `334` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 65), `335` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 61), `336` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 67), `337` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 73), `338` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 67), `339` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 65), `340` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 62), `341` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 66), `342` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 60), `343` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 62), `344` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 62), `345` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 61), `346` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `347` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `348` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `349` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `350` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `351` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `352` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `353` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `354` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `355` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `356` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `357` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `358` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `359` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `360` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `361` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `362` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `363` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `364` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `365` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `366` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `367` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `368` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `369` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `370` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `371` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `372` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `373` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `374` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `375` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `376` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `377` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `378` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `379` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `380` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `381` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `382` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `383` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `384` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `385` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `386` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `387` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `388` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `389` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `390` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `391` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `392` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `393` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `394` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `395` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `396` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `397` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `398` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `399` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `400` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `401` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `402` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `403` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `404` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `405` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `406` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi & welcome. Could you please expand your question with a reproducible example like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6086135 ? Also check datapasta for sharing parts of your data easily: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/datapasta-reprex.html

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm still new at this. I've tried providing dput() for the first five days of my data set

Answer (score 0):

`rowSums` is an R function, not SQL, and the `select` statement must use SQL syntax, not R code.   Also SQL is normally used with normalized data, i.e. long form, not wide form.

In any case, the dates in the question are unique so it seems that you just want a plain `rowSums`.

```
toDate <- function(y, m, d) as.Date(paste(y, m, d, sep = "-"))
DF <- with(y_t, data.frame(date = toDate(year, month, day), 
  sum = rowSums(y_t[-(1:3)], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

You could alternately do this with zoo (using `toDate` from above):

```
library(zoo)

z0 <- read.zoo(y_t, index = 1:3, FUN = toDate)
z <- zoo(rowSums(z0, na.rm = TRUE), time(z0))

plot(z)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think your code just adds up all the measurements instead of counting how many measurements were in one row. I need to later smooth the data and this is a prep step before that. I need the code to group the rows by the number of measurements in each and then smooth those groups separately

Comment: I had assumed the code in the question expressed your intention but if you are trying to count the number of non-NAs in each row then that would be `rowSums(!is.na(y_t[-(1:3)]))`

Comment: Do you have any idea about how I could group days by the number of measurements and then smooth those groups separately with bspline?

Comment: I am not clear on what you want to do.  You can use `tapply`, `ave` or `by` in base R to perform computations by group or use `group_by` in dplyr.